# Find occurrence of element in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

When the user types a value it checks if it exists in an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class array1 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int [] arraynumbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        for(int i = 0; i < arraynumbers.length; i++) {
            if (arraynumbers[i] == num){
                System.out.println("The value you have entered " + num + ", exists in the array");
        
            }else{
                System.out.println("The value you have entered does not exist in the array");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when ever I type a number to test it prints:

```
Enter a value
3
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered 3, exists in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
The value you have entered does not exist in the array
```

I am not 100% sure why this happens.

## Questions

1. Is it because there is nothing stopping it from finishing when it finds a number in the array?
2. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thank you

Comment: Enter a value
  3
  The value you have entered does not exist in the array
  The value you have entered does not exist in the array
  The value you have entered 3, exists in the array

Comment: please mark an answer to the question or update the question

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking out for a `break`. The entire loop is traversed even if your `num` is found. And either of the `if` or `else` block is executed. This would help you :

```
if (arraynumbers[i] == num) {
    System.out.println("The value you have entered " + num + ", exists in the array");
    break;
}
```

and probably to avoid printing anything in case the value is not matched you can remove the `else` block from your code.

Comment: This will still print all the values until you hit the one you've entered.

Comment: it would execute the else unless the value is found..which is what the OP is looking for I believe.

Comment: from the Q : "nothing stopping it from finishing when it finds a number in the array"

Comment: Hey, i tried adding this but know it says this:      Enter a value
3
       The value you have entered does not exist in the array 
       The value you have entered does not exist in the array
       The value you have entered 3, exists in the array

Comment: @JackRaiden : ideally thats what we could figure out from your question the intent was? or could you specify the required output clearly in the Question please

Comment: @nullpointer sorry it is kind of hard to format, but basically after I enter the number it prints "The value you have entered does not exist in the array" two times, then it says "The value you have entered 3, exists in the array"

Comment: if you don't want to print those two statement before finding the `num`, all you've got to do is remove the `else` block

Comment: I am trying to make it so when the number is entered the program tells the the user if it is entered by printing a message, if the number that was entered is not in the array in prints a message saying that.

Comment: @JackRaiden : i think this is what you are looking for in general 
http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Searcing.htm

Answer (score 2):

The break statement is definitely key.  However, if you want to print whether the number is found or not, you may want to consider something like this:

```
int num = scan.nextInt();
int [] arraynumbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
String srchStr = "does not exist";

for(int i = 0; i < arraynumbers.length; i++) {
    if (arraynumbers[i] == num) {
        srchStr = "exists";
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("The value you have entered " + num + ", " + srchStr + " in the array");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put that check in a loop like this, it means you check every number in the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraynumbers.length; i++) {
}
```

You could do this:

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

if (values.contains(num)) {
    System.out.println("The value you have entered " + num + ", exists in the array")
} else {
    System.out.println("The value you have entered does not exist in the array");
}
```